# Create environment from existing Project.toml file

Tags: julia

Suppose I already have a folder `MyFolder` containing a `Project.toml` and a `Manifest.toml` with some dependencies in it. How do I create an environment from these existing files? I know I can create an environment using `] generate EnvironmentName` but not sure about how to do this with existing files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must first **activate** your project.

In Pkg REPL mode ( ] )

```
activate path_to/MyFolder
```

Then you must **instantiate** it (by resolving version compatibilities if no `Manifest.toml` is present and by downloading dependencies)

```
instantiate
```

For further details `Pkg` official doc is [there](https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/)